# Sqoop import as textfile padding values

Tags: import, sqoop

I'm running sqoop version 1.4.6 trying to import a DB2 table as a comma delimited text file into HDFS. The resulting text file had all variables padded with white space before the comma if the value is less than the DB2 column size. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Seems that this is elevating the size of my file considerably.

Here is the import I was running:

```
sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=q1 --connect jdbc:db2://mydb2.com:50000/mydb --username xxxx --password xxxx 
--table mytables.table1 --target-dir /users/me/table1  --fields-terminated-by ',' --split-by id --direct
```

Comment: what is the data type of those columns in DB2 ?  you may have to use --query option in import and write the query which trims and perform cast.

Comment: It's a variety of data type: varchar, char, date, integer, smallint. Will try the query option.

Comment: sure , let me know if you run into any issues